# PowerPoint VB.Net VSTO Addin

Tags: vb.net, vsto, powerpoint

At present I am writing a VSTO addin in vb.net for PowerPoint that sets the footer to whatever option is selected on the list. However currently I’m able to set the slide footer and the handout master footer but I want to be able to set the print options handout footer.

So I can set the slide by using the below:

Dim p As PowerPoint.Presentation = a a.Slides(0).HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = classification

Handout master as below:

Dim p As PowerPoint.Presentation = a a.HandoutMaster.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = classification

But not where I would like the footer to be set which can be located here File > Print > Edit Header & Footer > Notes and Handouts

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option in the print dialog invokes the same dialog box that you get when you invoke it via Insert | Header & Footer and has the same effect.  It doesn't set up any special headers/footers that apply only when you print.  In fact, if you invoke the dialog from the print dialog but close the print dialog w/o printing, your handout master headers/footers are still set to whatever you asked for in the dialog box.

Your code will have the same effect.  The only difference, and and this is certainly due to a bug in PPT, is that if you set the handout footer via code, the dialog you get to from the print dialog doesn't reflect the changes.

But look at the print preview or what's actually printed.  Your code works.

[later] And after a bit more testing, I found that if you save/close/reopen the presentation, the dialog boxes get back in synch; they both report the correct footer information.

Comment: Amazing thanks so much Steve it was the bug that was throwing me off and thinking what I've done doesn't work...!